# How to match student's answer to actual answer

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop below where it displays data for each table row:

```
foreach ($studentData['questions'] as $questionId => $questionData) {

    ...

            echo '<td width="30%" class="answers">'.htmlspecialchars($questionData['answer']).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;

    ...

            echo '<td width="30%" class="studentanswer">'.htmlspecialchars($questionData['studentanswer']).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;


    }
```

What I want to do is that if an `studentanswer` matches an `answer`, then that `studentanswer` will turn green, if not a match then display incorrect answers in red, and if full `studentanswer` matches 100% with `answer` then I want a variable such as `$check` to display string station `fully correct` in green else if not 100% match then display string `not full correct` in red.

So for example the above code could display this:

```
Answer: B C
Student Answer: B D
```

The output of the above should display student answer `B` as green as it matches with answer `B` but student answer `D` should be red as there is no `D` in answer. The variable `$check` should state in red `not fully correct` as the student's answer is not fully correct, just partial.

But how can this be achieved?

UPDATE:

It is not changing color of text:

```
if($questionData['answer'] == $questionData['studentanswer']) {
$style = 'green';
$checked = 'Fully Correct';
} else {
$style = 'red';
$checked = 'Not Correct / Not Fully Correct';
}

        echo '<td width="30%" class="answers '.$style.'">'.htmlspecialchars($questionData['answer']).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;

...

        echo '<td width="30%" class="studentanswer '.$style.'">'.htmlspecialchars($questionData['studentanswer']).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
```

CSS:

```
.red{
color: red;
}

.green{
color: green;
}
```

Comment: Don't put $style inside the single quotes. Do this `'.$style.'`

Comment: @PriestVallon I changed ` class="$style"` to ` class=".$style."` but still no color

Comment: class shouldn't be declared twice. You should have something like `class="a b"` where a and b are separate classes.

Comment: @PriestVallon I don't quite understand that, do it mean I need to change on of the `$style` on top to a different variable name?

Comment: I changed your updated code to what I think it should be!

Comment: @PriestVallon I actually used your answer code and it worked well but only one little issue. If there a three answers and the students selected two correct answers and one incorrect answer, then it should display the 2 correct answers in green and the incorrect answer in red. With your code it is highlighting all answers as red. So if answer is A,B,D and student selected A,B,C, then A and B should be green and C should be red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$check = true;

foreach ($studentData['questions'] as $questionId => $questionData) {
    $studentAnswer = htmlspecialchars($questionData['studentanswer']);
    $answer = htmlspecialchars($questionData['answer']);
...

        echo '<td width="30%" class="answers">'.htmlspecialchars($questionData['answer']).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;

...
    if($answer == $studentAnswer)
    {
        echo '<td width="30%" class="studentanswer greenAnswer">'.htmlspecialchars($questionData['studentanswer']).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<td width="30%" class="studentanswer redAnswer">'.htmlspecialchars($questionData['studentanswer']).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        $check = false;
    }

}

if($check)
{
    echo '<p class="greenAnswer">Fully Correct!</p>';
}
else
{
    echo '<p class="redAnswer">Not Fully Correct!</p>';
}
```

In your CSS put the following:

```
greenAnswer
{
    color:green;
}

redAnswer
{
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: I tried changing code a bit but not able to get colour of text to occur, please look at my update

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if($questionData['answer'] == $questionData['studentanswer'] {
    $style = 'color:green';
    $checked = 'right';
} else {
    $style = 'color:red';
    $checked = 'not fully correct';
}
?>

...

<td width="30%" class="answers" style="<?php echo $style; ?>">
<?php echo $checked; ?>
```

Comment: I tried changing code a bit but not able to get colour of text to occur, please look at my update

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditions to achieve this.

With php's if() function, you can make sure your script meets certain conditions that you choose before processing a certain piece of code.

So to check if a student's answer matches the teachers answer, inside the loop, you'll add something like:

```
if( $questionData['studentanswer'] == $questionData['answer'] )
{
    // The answer was correct
}
else {
    // This is for the answer not being correct
}
```

This code just shows an example of how to achieve what you are trying to accomplish, of course you'll need to make your own to exactly match your needs.

If you have any other questions or need further assistance feel free to ask.